# Redirect loop .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel, redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yoursite\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/yoursite\.net\/" [R=301,L]
```

It creates redirect loop, but same code on other website runs fine, i am so angry, lost 2 hours on this.

This code supposed to redirect www & http to https.

Comment: If this works on a different site, how are we supposed to figure out from just these rules why it doesn't work? The problem must be somewhere else. Please [edit] more information into your question.

Comment: information like what?

Comment: I don't know, but clearly something is different between the two servers besides these four lines of .htaccess code.

Comment: Are you certain the other one doesn't also have `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`?  Looks like `yoursite.net` here is looping after rewriting to https because there's no condition to break it if https is already present.